# how to delete application on Android Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play

My application is pending publication, is it possible to delete it on Android Developer Console ? there is not any delete button on top-left side .

Is there any way ?

Comment: ok, my status is pending publish, there is no any button at this page to unpublished it.

Comment: no way you have to wait

Comment: Sorry I find answer said you can delete draft app before publishing app

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to delete projects from the Google Developer Console, however if you really don't want to see it then you can still unpublish it and filter it out from your screen.

### [image]

Comment: I want to cancel pending my app to publish.

Comment: Sorry I don't think that that is possible. As soon as you see that the "pending" is gone, just unpublish it, fix what you need to fix, and publish it again. Don't worry about people noticing your app as soon as it is published because that is very difficult. It take a while before that your app appears to the public in general search result.

Answer (score 0):

I never try it but I find this answer

you can delete before publish , but if once application published , you can only unpublished it

[image]